# Do I need to reveal card added with the Archived Memories?

Tags: android-netrunner

I've got no face-down cards in the archives. I play [Archived Memories](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01058). Do I need to show card I add to the HQ with it? Or the only thing runner can do is to watch the archives after this and figure out the missing card?

Comment: Assuming you didn't have to reveal, which I believe you do since the rules say you must show the card in the same state to the runner when you choose it (and the state is face up), you should reveal, it's easier that way for everyone since the runner can look at Archives at any time, like immediately before and immediately after the resolution of Archived Memories, and just figure out the difference.

Comment: Evaluating the diff could be challenging! And this might be the game point: good memory - competitive advantage. So it is not obvious what information is open in the game.

Comment: And time consuming, as far as I know it's not illegal to take notes, so the runner could write down the contents of archives then compare it after. Players take notes in MtG all the time for instance and I haven't seen a rule against it in ANR. Short cuts though are definitely preferable, since it saves alot of limited time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes you must show the card and they will see what it is.

*Visible* cards remain faceup when they go to the Archive.

The Corporation must show cards chosen by effects to the Runner without changing the face-up/down status, and if it is faceup the Runner will be able to see what it is.

Only facedown cards remain hidden from the Runner unless a game effect instructs you to reveal one.

If you were to have facedown cards in the Archive your opponent would see that you picked a facedown card but not see the front of it.

From the [official rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf)

> **Revealing Cards**
>
> If a Corporation card is not visible to the Runner when it is trashed
>   or discarded, then it is sent to Archives facedown. **If a Corporation
>   card is visible to the Runner when it is trashed or discarded, it is
>   sent to Archives faceup.**
>
> ***If a specific card or card type in an inactive state is chosen by a
>   card effect, the Corporation must show that card to the Runner without
>   changing its faceup or facedown status***. The Corporation only reveals
>   the card if it was facedown and the effect says he must reveal it.

Comment: It looks like most of your answer is irrelevant since OP says he has **no** face-down cards. The relevant answer is just this piece of your quote: "If a specific card or card type in an inactive state is chosen by a card effect, **the Corporation must show that card to the Runner without changing its faceup or facedown status.**" - i.e. face-up cards must still be shown.

Comment: Good point. I suppose I could phrase that differently. But the only cards that have visibility restrictions are face-down ones. Face-up cards are always visible. The rules are unfortunately sparse :/